# Using more than one Dropdown to create dynamic MySQL Statement and generate the

Tags: php, mysql

I am using more than one dropdown in may page the first being:-

```
function createCFAList()
{
$ajax = false;
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'ajax' && isset($_GET['cl'])) 
{
    $SelectedCFAName =  $_GET['cl'];
    $ajax = true;   
}

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `cfalist`.`CFA`
        FROM `amwplist` 
        INNER JOIN `cfalist` ON `cfalist`.`CFA_ID` = `amwplist`.`CFA_ID`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);            
$CFAlist = "<select id='cfa5' name='cfa5'>";            
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {         
    $CFAlist = $CFAlist . "<option value='" . $row['CFA'] ."'>" . $row['CFA'] ."</option>";         
}           
$CFAlist = $CFAlist . "</select>";  

return ($CFAlist);
}
```

The Second list being:-

```
function createStatusList()
    {
    $ajax = false;
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'ajax' && isset($_GET['ss'])) 
    {
        $SelectedStatus =  $_GET['ss'];
        $ajax = true;   
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `Status_ID`, 
            `Status_Type`
            FROM `workstatuslist` ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);            
    $Statuslist = "<select id='status4' name='status4'>";           
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {     
        if($row['Status_Type'] == "BOO in Progress")            
        {           

        $Statuslist = $Statuslist . "<option selected='" . $row['Status_Type'] ."'>" . $row['Status_Type'] ."</option>";    
        }           
    else            
        {           
        $Statuslist = $Statuslist . "<option value='" . $row['Status_Type'] ."'>" . $row['Status_Type'] ."</option>";   
        }           
    }           
    $Statuslist = $Statuslist . "</select>";



    return ($Statuslist);
    }
```

These two functions are placed in function.php and are called from AMWP.php to display the Dropdown. The selected options are stored in variables
  global $SelectedStatus and  global $SelectedCFAName 
using the following script in AMWP.php:-

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script>

        $('#status4').change(function()
        {
            var status4 = $('#status4').val();
            var req = $.get('functions.php', {ss: status4, action: 'ajax'});

        });

        $('#cfa5').change(function()
        {
            var cfa5 = $('#cfa5').val();
            var req = $.get('functions.php', {cl: cfa5, action: 'ajax'});

        });
    </script>



How may I store the Selected Option onChange to the variables declared global $SelectedStatus and  global $SelectedCFAName 
and then use them to create SQL Statement like whenever the Selected option is changed by the user



$sql="SELECT * FROM abc WHERE status LIKE $SelectedStatus AND cfa LIKE $SelectedCFAName";
```

Comment: Using Session Variable instead of global $SelectedStatus and  global $SelectedCFAName will do any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution at this URL
[SourceCodester Dot Com](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/5568/creating-dependent-dropdown-list-php-jquery-and-ajax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found One more good sample source at this link

[PHP Jquery Dropdown sample. Good One](https://phpgurukul.com/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-states-and-districts/)